# Couldn't find constant ONLINE

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

am using CodeIgniter  and i keep get  a error from the config file

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: constant() [function.constant]: Couldn't find constant ONLINE
Filename: libraries/co.php
Line Number: 534


A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/baahoot/public_html/Outlaws/system/core/Exceptions.php:185)
Filename: helpers/url_helper.php
Line Number: 542
```

i am not sure  what i am doing wrong this is a working code from git hub. I am new to php and would like to see how this worked on arvixe server using the mysql db anyone know how to fix  this type of error??

libraries/co.php somewhere around :534

```
function __construct() { 
    $CI =& get_instance(); 
    //$CI->form_validation->set_error_delimiters( '<br /><div class="response error-note">Error: ', '</div>' ); 
    if(constant('ONLINE') == FALSE): 
        //$CI->output->enable_profiler(TRUE); endif; 
    if(1 == 0 && constant('ONLINE') == TRUE ) { 
        echo $CI->load->view('temporary', '', true); exit; 
    } $CI->load->config('redis'); 
    $this->redis = ($CI->config->item('redis_active')); 
}
```

Comment: the script is looking for the constant ONLINE which is not defined, not much more to sya than that

Comment: Right and i am tring to figure out where that seting would be in the code  not sure  yet

Comment: well we have no way of knowing.

Comment: Chances are that `error_reporting` was disabled on your old server, so this error is not new at all (it's just been happening silently).

Comment: Duskwuff. i was think the same thing myself  so i  did   get tech at server company to  check  for me to make sure of all  settings. All tho  It was  no help at that time. Even tho i use Azure server  more then this Unix  one  I have found that Path of the uri set in one  way  to fix the error.

Answer (score 1):

Just use project-wide case sensitive search on  word `ONLINE`, any modern IDE and even editors have this functionality.

See where it's used and see if it's defined somewhere. If not - see what depends on it and define somewhere in the project.  It's a constant, not a variable, so it's a simple value you hard-code in your project, so there should be no problem with getting to know what it should be.

You may even try setting it to `true`, but that's just a guess. For further help, please update your question with the code from the method at

```
Filename: libraries/co.php
Line Number: 534
```

EDIT:

after you provided the code, I recommend to just make a dirty hack and add these lines to the `__construct` method right in the beginning so it would look like this.

```
function __construct() {
    if(!defined('ONLINE')) {
        define('ONLINE', true);
    }
```

If it will throw errors, try `false` instead of `true`. As I understand, this constant if `true` means that the page is in production, and in development if false, so play around as you wish.

Consider cleaning up all the code.

Comment: this is the code i have   function __construct()
 {
  $CI =& get_instance();
  //$CI->form_validation->set_error_delimiters( '<br /><div class="response error-note">Error: ', '</div>' );
  
  if(constant('ONLINE') == FALSE):
   //$CI->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);
  endif;
  
  if(1 == 0 && constant('ONLINE') == TRUE ) {
   echo $CI->load->view('temporary', '', true);
   exit;
  }
    
  $CI->load->config('redis');
  $this->redis = ($CI->config->item('redis_active'));
 }
 
 /* Undocumented code */

Comment: it seams to be this line all tho i am cant seam to figure it out yet     if(constant('ONLINE') == FALSE):

Comment: @JeffrySolinger next time edit your own question to provide more details like this code, as it is not readable here. This time I will do it for you

Comment: And to  just making sure that i am not just talking yang  I tried your idea the only thing you forgot is the every line of code after that needs that construct to work correctly 11134 lines of code  after that  now dead  using your idea. Makes   me think to never ask for your help!!!!

Comment: Um, sorry, where do you think that was copy pasted from? Ragequit as long as you wish. Constant `ONLINE` is not part of CodeIgniter, but rather part of your project, which one of the developers be it you or someone else who worked on it implemented. I provided the way to fix this as you have not given enough information or even codebase to find out how it should be fixed properly. When asking questions or posting rage comments consider reading the FAQ question of SO, especially how to ask questions, what to provide and how you should help others when you request their help with your problems.

Comment: For my words not to be considered naked to you, try to find file `libraries/co.php` in the CodeIgniter repository: https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/